# Property of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular for my frontend, i have a *ngFor that iterates the objects, but in that object i have this entity.

```
export class Usuario {
id: number;
username: string;
password: string;
nombre: string;
apellido: string;
email: string;
createAt: string;
roles: string[] = []; }
```

in roles i'm setting a JSON with, the role id, and the name of the role but i only need to retrieve the name of it.

```
                <tr *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios">
                    <td>Imagen</td>
                    <!-- <td *ngIf="authService.hasRole('ROLE_USER')"><img *ngIf="cliente?.foto" (click)="abrirModal(cliente)" src="http://localhost:8080/api/uploads/img/{{cliente.foto}}" class="img-thumbnail rounded"
                        style="width: 64px; cursor: pointer;">
                        <img *ngIf="!cliente?.foto" (click)="abrirModal(cliente)" src="http://localhost:8080/images/no-image.png" alt="Sin foto" class="img-thumbnail rounded"
                        style="width: 64px; cursor: pointer;"></td> -->
                    <td>{{usuario.nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{usuario.apellido}}</td>
                    <td>{{usuario.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{usuario.createAt}}</td>
                    <td>{{usuario.roles | json}}</td> -- this is where --
                    <td><button type="button" (click)="abrirModal(usuario)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editar</button></td>
                </tr>
```

what i need to do to get only the name? can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You wrote your title as `Property of undefined`, but you didnt state about the error in your description. Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `Usuario` class looks not correct. You said that `roles` property has an array of object(which has `id` and `name`), but your `roles` type is `string[]` which is not correct.

I think it should be:

```
roles: { id: string, name: string }[];
```

However, if you want to extract only names from the `roles`, you can use `*ngFor`(that you already know).

So, this line:

```html
<td>{{usuario.roles | json}}</td>
```

becomes:

```html
<td>
   <span *ngFor="let role of roles">
       {{ role.name }}
   </span>
</td>
```